# php include using server username instead of domain name

Tags: php

My php line in tommyburn.co.uk/westancroft/index.php:

```
$cwd = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   echo $cwd;
   $path =  $cwd."/westancroft/Pages/Main/Main.php";
   include_once($path);
```

is returning:

> tommyburn.co.uk
>   Warning: include_once(tommyburn.co.uk/westancroft/Pages/Main/Main.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tommybu1/public_html/westancroft/index.php on line 6

Why is it trying to find it at the username , instead of at the domain name?
How can I fix this?
Many thanks
Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include_once` takes the system file path, not a web url which is what you have.

If you want the current working directory, use [`getcwd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

If you need an absolute URL, use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the file where you are at the moment and work your way from there.

Comment: I want to use an absolute URL but not from where I am, because the included file is in another included file, and so the current location varies.

Comment: @Tommy research and use `dirname(__FILE__)`, that URL will never change!

Comment: Ok, but the line No such file or directory in /home/tommybu1/public_html/westancroft/index.php on line 6 means that it is looking for it at the current directory, not from the root.

Comment: @Tommy first get the value of dirname(__FILE__). Then work your way to it. For example if you get back `c:/windows/users/test/` and the file you want is stored in the `windows/test2`, then you need this: `dirname(__FILE__).'/../../test2/yourfile.php'`

Comment: Thanks, That has sorted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$cwd` should probably be either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is the host from the current request, ie: the domain... which is invalid in your case.

Comment: I want to use the domain though. because Im getting the absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work?

```
$cwd = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skuntsel - I agree this is probably a comment but you need rep to comment and new users cant comment on other's posts. See  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges